# Dynamically load jQuery and then Typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I'm trying to dynamically load jQuery and then dynamically load the Typeahead.js jQuery plugin.

I'm able to load jQuery but the typeahead plugin doesn't seem to load. The first part of the code checks for jQuery and dynamically loads it if it doesn't exist.

After jQuery has loaded, I'm attempting to load Typeahead using $.getScript which is used in the jQuery documentation to load jQuery plugins. However, the Typehead plugin doesn't seem to load as I'm getting errors when I try to call Bloodhound (the suggestion engine in Typeahead).

I confirmed that the typeahead code shown below works by throwing it into a Rails app. When used with the jquery-rails gem and the asset pipeline, the typeahead code properly populates my input box with the JSON response. However, I can't rely on Rails and when I try to separate out the code, I am unable to dynamically load the libraries in the proper order.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
(function() {

    // Localize jQuery variable
    var jQuery;

    /******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
    if (window.jQuery === undefined) {
      var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
      script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
      script_tag.setAttribute("src",
        "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js");
        if (script_tag.readyState) {
          script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
            if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
              scriptLoadHandler();
            }
          };
        } else { // Other browsers
          script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
        }
        // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
        var parentHead = (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement)
        parentHead.insertBefore(script_tag, parentHead.firstChild);
    } else {
      // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
      jQuery = window.jQuery;
      main();
    }

    /******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
    function scriptLoadHandler() {
      // Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
      // new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
      jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
      // Load Typeahead
      // Call our main function
      main();
    }

    /******** Our main function ********/
    function main() {
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

     /******* This is the call to load typeahead *******/
        var url = "https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"
        $.getScript(url, function(){
          var companies = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            limit: 3000,
            prefetch: {
              // url points to a json file that contains an array of country names, see
              // https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/gh-pages/data/countries.json
              url: '/accounts.json',
            }
          });
          // kicks off the loading/processing of `local` and `prefetch`
          companies.initialize();

          // passing in `null` for the `options` arguments will result in the default
          // options being used
          $('#the-basics .search .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
            name: 'companies',
            displayKey: 'name',
            // `ttAdapter` wraps the suggestion engine in an adapter that
            // is compatible with the typeahead jQuery plugin
            source: companies.ttAdapter()
          });
        });
      });
    }
  })();
```

Comment: What DOES happen? Are you seeing any error messages? Can you confirm that the `.getScript` call is successfully completing and the callback is called?

Comment: I get a reference error for Bloodhound and an error in the Typeahead.js source. I confirmed that the $.getScript method is called because I reach my debugger inside the callback but Typeahead doesn't seem to load.

The two errors:
1. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isArray' of undefined
2. Uncaught ReferenceError: Bloodhound is not defined

Comment: The `isArray` error is coming from the attempt to parse the loaded typeahead code, and is the first use in that script of '$'. It's acting like it failed to resolve `window.jQuery`. Looks like it's time to toss a breakpoint in at the top of the callback and see what the state of `window.jQuery` is at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried writing dependency loaders before and it's very complex, especially on the cross-browser side. Last year I had a similar problem to yours where I need to load jQuery (maybe) and a bunch of other libraries in a very specific order. I could get it to work in say Chrome, but not IE, etc. Timing issues seem to creep up every time I made a change!

After trying many lines of code not dissimilar to yours, I gave up and eventually found: http://headjs.com/

Since then, I've been using HeadJs pretty much exclusively and my code is a few lines (as opposed to the massive monstrosities I was constructing before.)

Not sure if using a library works for you, but if it does, I highly recommend this one.

By the way, note there is a "head.ready" event that will replace your usual Dom Ready. This event fires WHEN your libraries are all nicely loaded and ready to go! TIP: You will want to use head.ready to fire off all your javascript actions!

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I don't have the option to use something like headjs.com. I need to be able to pass this code around without writing explicit script tags in the source.

Comment: Understood. However, headjs is open source... you could review the head.load.js file to gain insight into how the developers pull this off. I can tell you, from experience, that timing is going to get you in trouble every time in various browsers and different user connection speeds! In any case, if it helps you, the code is here and appears to be well commented: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/headjs/1.0.3/head.load.js

Comment: RequireJs is another very popular library that handles loading of assets and is also open source. http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.14/comments/require.js - seems also well commented.